# For any metric $g_{ab}$ show that $g^{ab}g_{ab}=N$ where $N$ is the dimension of the manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

I'm bugged by this question of my physics book... As far as I know, shouldn't the product $g^{ab}g_{ab}$ be precisely the $N\times N$ identity matrix (given the fact that, expressing the contravariant and covariant metric tensor as matrices, they are the inverse matrix of each other)?

Comment: No, it is the *trace* of the identity matrix.  Note both $a$ and $b$ are summed over (and we use $g$ symmetric).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use the Einstein notation, you'll see that
$$ g^{ab}g_{ab}=\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^{\dim M}\sum_{b=1}^{\dim M}g^{ab}g_{ab},$$
where $M$ is your manifold. As you said, $g^{ab}$ are the coefficients of the inverse of $(g_{ab})$. In other words,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\dim M}g^{ak}g_{bk}=\delta^a_{\;b},$$
where $\delta^a_{\;b}$ is the Kronecker delta. It follows that
$$ g^{ab}g_{ab}=\sum_{a=1}^{\dim M}\delta^a_{\;a}=\sum_{a=1}^{\dim M} 1=\dim M.$$